# Select comma separated values from single column

Tags: mysql

Below is the MySQL data table in which we have 5 lookup columns and their respective names in lookup_list column separated by commas. I want to select each lookup column name separately from lookup_list column like: 
Invoice_Lookup as Lookup_1 Name
Leadlist_Lookup as Lookup_2 Name 
and so on.

[image: Sample Data Table]

Comment: What is the desired result? I mean after select name from Lookup list what you want to display?

Comment: It should be like, Select
Invoice_Lookup as Lookup1 Name, 
Leadlist_Lookup as Lookup_2 Name, 
BTNHistory_Lookup as Lookup_3 Name,

as so on

Comment: So you want to use output of query as a column name in another query?

Comment: Yes, i want them as column.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: show us exactly the desire return value you want.  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normalize your data. 
But by using SUBSTRING_INDEX you can split your Lookup_list into columns like so

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Lookup_list, ',', 1), ',', -1) AS Lookup_1
, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Lookup_list, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS Lookup_2
, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Lookup_list, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS Lookup_3
, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Lookup_list, ',', 4), ',', -1) AS Lookup_4
, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Lookup_list, ',', 5), ',', -1) AS Lookup_5
FROM
 [table]
```

Comment: This doesnt make sense. Will print the same values for all rows.

Comment: true but don't blame me @JuanCarlosOropeza but it splits Lookup_list into columns like the topic starter asked for in his comments.... his data doesn't make sense annyhow it should be normalized

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks. And sorry for very vague question.